# fortran redirect only some output to stdout

Tags: fortran, io-redirection

I am kind of new to fortran and have come across the following problem. Let us consider the following simple "output.for":

```
implicit none
character*10 str1,str2

call get_command_argument(1,setupfile)
open(20, file = setupfile)
read(20,*) str1, str2

write(6,*) str1        ! I want this to go to terminal output
write(6,*) str2        ! I'd like to have this redirected to a file

end
```

And now I invoke the code as: `./output setupfile > outfile.dat` 
How do I force "str1" to be printed to terminal output while "str2" to be redirected to outfile.dat?

Comment: There is no way. Update your code. Btw, use * instead of 6, it is much better.

Comment: Try `write(0,*) str1` .  Unit 0 is often points to stderr.

Comment: That's a good hack, but requires a change of the code as well. However, the same way * is better than `6`, `error_unit` from `iso_fortran_env` is better than hard-coded `0`.

Comment: @Vladimir F, according to your last comment how do I change my statement write(6,*) str1 using the `iso_fortran_env' to get the output to the terminal?

Comment: Well `use fortran_env` at the beginning and then `write(error_unit,*) str1`

Comment: @Vladimir F, when I try to compile my code with  "use fortran_env" and write(error_unit,*) str1, I am getting the error message " Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'fortran_env.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory". Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, a typo, it is `use iso_fortran_env`.

Comment: @Vladimir F, thanks that worked :)